# c++ Having trouble about changing name on console window

Tags: c++, window

```
LPCTSTR Process = ("Test game");



LPCTSTR windowName = Process(" Text");
system("color 0a");
SetConsoleTitle(windowName);
```

Can anyone please make this posiblle?

Answer (score 2):

To change the current console title you can use the [SetConsoleTitle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686050(v=vs.85).aspx) WinAPI function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main(){
    wchar_t newTitle[255] = L"My New Console Title";
    SetConsoleTitle(newTitle); // set the current console title
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But i want to have both the LPCTSTR and some text So i can make it say Test game   text as seen in my example above